# Bake a texture with Mapping and Texture coordinates nodes

Tags: texturing, node-editor, texture-baking, texture-coordinates, vector-mapping

Is it possible to bake a modified texture (diffuse, normal map, etc etc.) with the nodes Texture coordinates and Mapping?

I've tried to do it but the result doesn't change,
the texture is the same as before the modification.

[image]

Surely I'm wrong something since I've just started to learn about baking and use it, I've searched a bit on the internet but nobody talks about this topic.

### Nodes and Bake Config.

[image]
[image]

Am I wrong because there is a precise method to do it or is it not possible?

Comment: I don't really know either, maybe it's just not possible. It seems you're talking about using like some vector from a Geometry node or something and then put that into the vector of the image, and the bake process uses it as the position where the result of the calculations is saved on the canvas.